# JPA CriteriaBuilder: fetch specific columns on joined entity

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

Given the following two entities:

```
public class Performer {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "performers_characters",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "performer_id", nullable = false, updatable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "character_id", nullable = false, updatable = false))
    private Set<Character> characters = Sets.newHashSet();
}
```

And:

```
public class Character {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private Boolean alive;

    private String placeOfBirth;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "characters")
    private Set<Performer> performers = Sets.newHashSet();
}
```

I want to create query, using Criteria Builder, that will generate the equivalent SQL:

```
SELECT performer0_.id AS id1_11_0_,
       character2_.id AS id1_0_1_,
       performer0_.name AS name7_11_0_,
       character2_.name AS name12_0_1_,
       characters1_.character_id AS character_id2_12_0__
FROM performer performer0_
INNER JOIN performers_characters characters1_ ON performer0_.id=characters1_.performer_id
INNER JOIN character character2_ ON characters1_.character_id=character2_.id
```

So basically, everything from Performer should be selected, but from Character, only id and name should be selected.

Currently I'm stuck with the following:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Performer> baseCriteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Performer.class);
Root<Performer> baseRoot = baseCriteriaQuery.from(Performer.class);
baseCriteriaQuery.select(baseRoot);
baseRoot.fetch("characters");
TypedQuery<Performer> baseTypedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(baseCriteriaQuery);
List<Performer> baseEntityList = baseTypedQuery.getResultList();
```

This work fine, except that from both Character and Performer, all columns are selected.

Comment: Why? What is the use case?

Comment: I'm build an API where, when entity is retrieved, only ID and name is displayed for every related entity of different type, so client can query further using the ID or name. Effectively I don't need to fetch every column from the related tables.

Answer (score 0):

With JPA this would only be possible if you specify the fields that you don't want to load as lazy.

```
@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private String placeOfBirth;

@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Boolean alive;
```

But the question is why do you want to do that? Both fields are small items and with LAZY you have more SQL calls to fetch the data.

Comment: And, with Hibernate, only if you also enabled byte code enhancement.

Comment: That is just an example. Potentially there could be joins to more than 5 tables, and to multiple entities could be fetched from every joined table. I just want name and ID for every table being fetched, because that's the only columns that gonna be used.

Comment: To make it short. This is not possible